# GAE/Python every request caused a new process

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm receiving this warning when any single request comes in. It seems that the process will be shut down immediately after it processed the request.

Since I can't post image, I'll copy and paste some logs.

```
2012-11-25 09:12:37.441 /task/process-block 200 1609ms 0kb AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)
I 2012-11-25 09:12:37.440 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ...

2012-11-25 09:12:26.054 /task/process-block 200 2160ms 0kb AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)
I 2012-11-25 09:12:26.053 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ...

2012-11-25 09:12:14.036 /task/process-block 200 3156ms 0kb AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)
I 2012-11-25 09:12:14.036 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ...
```

To my understanding, a processing should stay for at least 15 minutes when there's no request coming in, but the above log shows that the process is killed not longer than 10 seconds. Currently I can see only one instance typed dynamic (and hours before I can not see any instance running when I checked out), and that instance don't respond to request even it finished processing the previous one. Instead, a new instance will be generated and response the request.

Is it a bug or a setting problem? My app is using python 2.7 thread-safe, I set the max idle instances to 1, and min pending latency to 15.0s.

#### Update:

I changed Max Idle Instances to 50, the problem still remains.

Comment: Is this in production or on the `dev_appserver` server?

Comment: @voscausa no, it's a free application. my other free apps don't have this issue

Comment: @bossylobster it's in production server

Comment: Is it handling the request fully before it appears to shut down? (i.e., did client get the correct response, and/or was the input handled properly)? If not, is it possible you're blowing past a memory limit?

Comment: @ckchan from the logs I can say the request is fully handled. Sometimes I can see an instance can be able to serve 6 or more request (not sequentially. This instance may serve the 1st, 3rd, 8th, 9th, but other requests will be served by other new one-time-serve instances) without being shut down.

Comment: @ckchan every 10 seconds, a new task will be pushed to queue and be processed. processing one task will take around 3s (because nearly every request will cause an new instance, so it's pretty slow). An instance should be able to handle all the tasks without other instances' help. Also my app won't use a lot of memory. From Instances page I can see, an instance will use about 30M memory.

Comment: @ckchan the most wired thing is, there's an dynamic instance available (it's age is 2 hours more), but it only served two requests. Nearly all other requests will be served by newly generated instances.

Answer (score 0):

After two day's running, the problem disappears. The task been pushed into queue is a pretty time consuming task since it need to retrieve some data from internet, and usually it will take more than 1 second.

Now the task's running time is reduced to 200ms in average because it has caught up with the data producer, so most of the time it just found that there's no more data to process and returned.

So I guess when GAE receives a request, it will first predict if this request can be done within 1 second. If the answer is yes, GAE will use an existing process to deal with it; or it will start a new process and keep the old one for processing other short-time requests. This could explain why there always is a new process, and this could also explain why some instance has a pretty long age but do not have many requests processed.